# Excel multiple criteria to retain rows that prioritise during deduplication - VBA macro or other method

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I need a solution to this so would any kind people out there that can help a novice Excel user?

I have three columns. Column A contains 10000 email addresses, Column B contains three values (Dr, Prof, Student), Column C contains title of project.

The problem: Same people (judging by email address) appear in this spreadsheet more than once with different value in column B (same person appears as Prof, Dr and Student).

Solution required: create three columns that count how many times same email address (Column A) appears on column A for each of the column b values. So I will then have a count of how many times an email address appears on the spreadsheet per (column b value).

Then deduplicate spreadsheet by Column A and B in a way that prioritises as follows : 1) prof over Dr and Student and 2) dr over student. In this way the rows to be retained will prioritise Professors and doctors over students.

Comment: Hi there, Is this a one time excercise? or do you need to do this repeatedly? It can be done in both Excel and VBA, so I would need to know how you want to use it.

Comment: This is a one off exercise. I tried with multiple countifs but iam not doing something right and i get wrong results

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you do the following (please create a backup first):

1. Search and replace 'Professor'-> '_Professor'
2. Sort the data by  Email and Title (Prof,dr,student). *You should now see the groups of duplicate email addresses, where the record to keep is the top one*
3. In a new column (touching the data range) enter *True* at row 1 (assuming  and you don't have headers)
4. Add a formula to the new column at row 2. (assuming the emails are in column A).

`=A1<>A2`

4. Extend the formula down
5. Copy/ paste the new column to values
6. Sort the data by the new column
7. All the rows that have *False* in the new column can be deleted.

Comment: I tried it and it worked as a charm but  the requester changed the requirements a bit. So they want to prioritise when deduplicating as above but before doing so they want to have three columns that would count number of Grants per email/Professor , per email/student per email/Dr. So for each unique individual a number for how many times their email appears as that of a professor, of a Dr and of a CoApp. I am not sure if i am making sense...

Comment: In that case you'd best add a column before you previous 7 steps. That column should be the combination of email and title(prof,dr,student) by combining the strings as `=A1&B1` if those are the columns. Then build a countif on that column like `=countif("$F$1:$F$10000","=" & F1)` if F is the combined column. Extend the formula down, so row 2 gets & F2 etc. This will reveal the amount of occurances. Copy that column to values and then do the previous 7 steps